# Adding a Mask as a see-through object in Flex

Tags: flash, flex4.5

I'm trying to add an overlay over my main scene in Flex, with a see thru.

The idea is that users can only interact with the elements exposed thru the Ellipse.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Our black overlay -->
<s:Graphic width="100%" height="100%" cacheAsBitmap="true" mask="{this.focus}"
           maskType="{MaskType.CLIP}">
    <s:Rect width="100" height="100">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0.7" color="0x000000" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Graphic> 

<!-- Our mask -->
<s:Group id="focus" cacheAsBitmap="true">
    <s:Ellipse id="ellipse" x="150" y="150" width="100" height="100">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Ellipse>    
</s:Group>
```

In Flash Builder, the overlay seems to work as desired:

[image: Overlay with see-thru in Flash Builder]

But here is the effect as rendered in the game:

[image: Effect in Application]

Is the opposite of what I'm looking for!  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

------------- EDIT-----------------

@HotN:  Thanks for your help, is there anyway to add an alpha to the surrounding area?  The idea is for the rest of the game to be visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to mask the black rectangle, try putting your street image on top of the black rectangle and using the ellipse as the mask for your active image instead.